# WinRM and HTTP services impossible to start

Tags: http, windows-server-2012-r2, service, winrm

I have a new windows 2012 R2 server and here are softwares and roles installed :

```
- nxFilter
- TeamViewer
```

Get-WindowsFeature command result :

```
Success Restart Needed Exit Code      Feature Result
------- -------------- ---------      --------------
True    No             Success        {Fonctionnalités HTTP communes, Document p...


PS C:\Users\Administrateur> Get-WindowsFeature

Display Name                                            Name                       Install State
------------                                            ----                       -------------
[X] Accès à distance                                    RemoteAccess                   Installed
    [ ] DirectAccess et VPN (accès à distance)          DirectAccess-VPN               Available
    [ ] Routage                                         Routing                        Available
    [ ] Web Application Proxy                           Web-Application-Proxy          Available
[ ] Expérience Windows Server Essentials                ServerEssentialsRole           Available
[ ] Hyper-V                                             Hyper-V                        Available
[ ] Serveur d'applications                              Application-Server             Available
    [ ] .NET Framework 4.5                              AS-NET-Framework               Available
    [ ] Accès réseau COM+                               AS-Ent-Services                Available
    [ ] Partage de port TCP                             AS-TCP-Port-Sharing            Available
    [ ] Prise en charge du serveur Web (IIS)            AS-Web-Support                 Available
    [ ] Prise en charge du service d'activation des ... AS-WAS-Support                 Available
        [ ] Activation des canaux nommés                AS-Named-Pipes                 Available
        [ ] Activation HTTP                             AS-HTTP-Activation             Available
        [ ] Activation Message Queuing                  AS-MSMQ-Activation             Available
        [ ] Activation TCP                              AS-TCP-Activation              Available
    [ ] Transactions distribuées                        AS-Dist-Transaction            Available
        [ ] Transactions WS-Atomic                      AS-WS-Atomic                   Available
        [ ] Transactions réseau entrantes               AS-Incoming-Trans              Available
        [ ] Transactions réseau sortantes               AS-Outgoing-Trans              Available
[ ] Serveur de télécopie                                Fax                            Available
[X] Serveur DHCP                                        DHCP                           Installed
[X] Serveur DNS                                         DNS                            Installed
[ ] Serveur Web (IIS)                                   Web-Server                     Available
    [ ] Serveur Web                                     Web-WebServer                  Available
        [ ] Fonctionnalités HTTP communes               Web-Common-Http                Available
            [ ] Contenu statique                        Web-Static-Content             Available
            [ ] Document par défaut                     Web-Default-Doc                Available
            [ ] Erreurs HTTP                            Web-Http-Errors                Available
            [ ] Exploration de répertoire               Web-Dir-Browsing               Available
            [ ] Publication WebDAV                      Web-DAV-Publishing             Available
            [ ] Redirection HTTP                        Web-Http-Redirect              Available
        [ ] Intégrité et diagnostics                    Web-Health                     Available
            [ ] Journalisation HTTP                     Web-Http-Logging               Available
            [ ] Journal ODBC                            Web-ODBC-Logging               Available
            [ ] Journalisation personnalisée            Web-Custom-Logging             Available
            [ ] Observateur de demandes                 Web-Request-Monitor            Available
            [ ] Outils de journalisation                Web-Log-Libraries              Available
            [ ] Suivi de traces                         Web-Http-Tracing               Available
        [ ] Performance                                 Web-Performance                Available
            [ ] Compression du contenu statique         Web-Stat-Compression           Available
            [ ] Compression de contenu dynamique        Web-Dyn-Compression            Available
        [ ] Sécurité                                    Web-Security                   Available
            [ ] Filtrage des demandes                   Web-Filtering                  Available
            [ ] Authentification de base                Web-Basic-Auth                 Available
            [ ] Authentification Digest                 Web-Digest-Auth                Available
            [ ] Authentification par mappage de cert... Web-Client-Auth                Available
            [ ] Authentification par mappage de cert... Web-Cert-Auth                  Available
            [ ] Authentification Windows                Web-Windows-Auth               Available
            [ ] Autorisation d'URL                      Web-Url-Auth                   Available
            [ ] Prise en charge centralisée des cert... Web-CertProvider               Available
            [ ] Restrictions IP et de domaine           Web-IP-Security                Available
        [ ] Développement d'applications                Web-App-Dev                    Available
            [ ] ASP                                     Web-ASP                        Available
            [ ] ASP.NET 3.5                             Web-Asp-Net                    Available
            [ ] ASP.NET 4.5                             Web-Asp-Net45                  Available
            [ ] CGI                                     Web-CGI                        Available
            [ ] Extensibilité .NET 3.5                  Web-Net-Ext                    Available
            [ ] Extensibilité .NET 4.5                  Web-Net-Ext45                  Available
            [ ] Extensions ISAPI                        Web-ISAPI-Ext                  Available
            [ ] Fichiers Include côté serveur           Web-Includes                   Available
            [ ] Filtres ISAPI                           Web-ISAPI-Filter               Available
            [ ] Initialisation d'applications           Web-AppInit                    Available
            [ ] Protocole WebSocket                     Web-WebSockets                 Available
    [ ] Outils de gestion                               Web-Mgmt-Tools                 Available
        [ ] Console de gestion IIS                      Web-Mgmt-Console               Available
        [ ] Compatibilité avec la gestion IIS 6         Web-Mgmt-Compat                Available
            [ ] Compatibilité de métadonnées IIS 6      Web-Metabase                   Available
            [ ] Compatibilité avec le service WMI IIS 6 Web-WMI                        Available
            [ ] Console de gestion IIS 6                Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console          Available
            [ ] Outils de script IIS 6                  Web-Lgcy-Scripting             Available
        [ ] Scripts et outils de gestion IIS            Web-Scripting-Tools            Available
        [ ] Service de gestion                          Web-Mgmt-Service               Available
    [ ] Serveur FTP                                     Web-Ftp-Server                 Available
        [ ] Service FTP                                 Web-Ftp-Service                Available
        [ ] Extensibilité FTP                           Web-Ftp-Ext                    Available
[X] Services AD DS                                      AD-Domain-Services             Installed
[ ] Services AD FS (Active Directory Federation Serv... ADFS-Federation                Available
[ ] Services AD LDS (Active Directory Lightweight Di... ADLDS                          Available
[ ] Services AD RMS (Active Directory Rights Managem... ADRMS                          Available
    [ ] Active Directory Rights Management Server       ADRMS-Server                   Available
    [ ] Prise en charge de la fédération des identités  ADRMS-Identity                 Available
[ ] Services Bureau à distance                          Remote-Desktop-Services        Available
    [ ] Accès Bureau à distance par le Web              RDS-Web-Access                 Available
    [ ] Gestionnaire de licences des services Bureau... RDS-Licensing                  Available
    [ ] Hôte de session Bureau à distance               RDS-RD-Server                  Available
    [ ] Hôte de virtualisation des services Bureau à... RDS-Virtualization             Available
    [ ] Passerelle des services Bureau à distance       RDS-Gateway                    Available
    [ ] Service Broker pour les connexions Bureau à ... RDS-Connection-Broker          Available
[ ] Services d'activation en volume                     VolumeActivation               Available
[X] Services d'impression et de numérisation de docu... Print-Services                 Installed
    [X] Serveur d'impression                            Print-Server                   Installed
    [ ] Impression Internet                             Print-Internet                 Available
    [ ] Serveur de numérisation distribuée              Print-Scan-Server              Available
    [ ] Service LPD                                     Print-LPD-Service              Available
[X] Services de certificats Active Directory            AD-Certificate                 Installed
    [X] Autorité de certification                       ADCS-Cert-Authority            Installed
    [ ] Inscription de l'autorité de certification v... ADCS-Web-Enrollment            Available
    [ ] Répondeur en ligne                              ADCS-Online-Cert               Available
    [ ] Service d'inscription de périphérique réseau    ADCS-Device-Enrollment         Available
    [ ] Service Web Inscription de certificats          ADCS-Enroll-Web-Svc            Available
    [ ] Service Web Stratégie d'inscription de certi... ADCS-Enroll-Web-Pol            Available
[ ] Services de déploiement Windows                     WDS                            Available
    [ ] Serveur de déploiement                          WDS-Deployment                 Available
    [ ] Serveur de transport                            WDS-Transport                  Available
[X] Services de fichiers et de stockage                 FileAndStorage-Services        Installed
    [X] Services de fichiers et iSCSI                   File-Services                  Installed
        [X] Serveur de fichiers                         FS-FileServer                  Installed
        [X] BranchCache pour fichiers réseau            FS-BranchCache                 Installed
        [ ] Déduplication des données                   FS-Data-Deduplication          Available
        [ ] Dossiers de travail                         FS-SyncShareService            Available
        [X] Espaces de noms DFS                         FS-DFS-Namespace               Installed
        [ ] Fournisseur de stockage cible iSCSI (fou... iSCSITarget-VSS-VDS            Available
        [ ] Gestionnaire de ressources du serveur de... FS-Resource-Manager            Available
        [ ] Réplication DFS                             FS-DFS-Replication             Available
        [ ] Serveur cible iSCSI                         FS-iSCSITarget-Server          Available
        [ ] Serveur pour NFS                            FS-NFS-Service                 Available
        [ ] Service Agent VSS du serveur de fichiers    FS-VSS-Agent                   Available
    [X] Services de stockage                            Storage-Services               Installed
[ ] Services de stratégie et d'accès réseau             NPAS                           Available
    [ ] Serveur NPS (Network Policy Server)             NPAS-Policy-Server             Available
    [ ] Autorité HRA (Health Registration Authority)    NPAS-Health                    Available
    [ ] HCAP (Host Credential Authorization Protocol)   NPAS-Host-Cred                 Available
[ ] Services WSUS (Windows Server Update Services)      UpdateServices                 Available
    [ ] WID Database                                    UpdateServices-WidDB           Available
    [ ] WSUS Services                                   UpdateServices-Services        Available
    [ ] Base de données                                 UpdateServices-DB              Available
[ ] Assistance à distance                               Remote-Assistance              Available
[X] Base de données interne Windows                     Windows-Internal-Dat...        Installed
[X] BranchCache                                         BranchCache                    Installed
[ ] Chiffrement de lecteur BitLocker                    BitLocker                      Available
[ ] Client d'impression Internet                        Internet-Print-Client          Available
[ ] Client pour NFS                                     NFS-Client                     Available
[ ] Client Telnet                                       Telnet-Client                  Available
[ ] Client TFTP                                         TFTP-Client                    Available
[ ] Clustering avec basculement                         Failover-Clustering            Available
[ ] Compression différentielle à distance               RDC                            Available
[ ] Data Center Bridging                                Data-Center-Bridging           Available
[ ] Déverrouillage réseau BitLocker                     BitLocker-NetworkUnlock        Available
[ ] DirectPlay                                          Direct-Play                    Available
[ ] Équilibrage de la charge réseau                     NLB                            Available
[ ] Expérience audio-vidéo haute qualité Windows        qWave                          Available
[ ] Extension ISS Management OData                      ManagementOdata                Available
[ ] Extension WinRM IIS                                 WinRM-IIS-Ext                  Available
[X] Fonctionnalités de .NET Framework 3.5               NET-Framework-Features         Installed
    [X] .NET Framework 3.5 (inclut .NET 2.0 et 3.0)     NET-Framework-Core             Installed
    [ ] Activation HTTP                                 NET-HTTP-Activation            Available
    [ ] Activation non-HTTP                             NET-Non-HTTP-Activ             Available
[X] Fonctionnalités de .NET Framework 4.5               NET-Framework-45-Fea...        Installed
    [X] .NET Framework 4.5                              NET-Framework-45-Core          Installed
    [X] ASP.NET 4.5                                     NET-Framework-45-ASPNET        Installed
    [X] Services WCF                                    NET-WCF-Services45             Installed
        [ ] Activation des canaux nommés                NET-WCF-Pipe-Activat...        Available
        [ ] Activation HTTP                             NET-WCF-HTTP-Activat...        Available
        [ ] Activation Message Queuing (MSMQ)           NET-WCF-MSMQ-Activat...        Available
        [ ] Activation TCP                              NET-WCF-TCP-Activati...        Available
        [X] Partage de port TCP                         NET-WCF-TCP-PortShar...        Installed
[X] Gestion de stratégie de groupe                      GPMC                           Installed
[ ] Gestion du stockage Windows basé sur des normes     WindowsStorageManage...        Available
[ ] IFilter TIFF Windows                                Windows-TIFF-IFilter           Available
[ ] IIS Hostable Web Core                               Web-WHC                        Available
[X] Interfaces utilisateur et infrastructure            User-Interfaces-Infra          Installed
    [X] Outils et infrastructure de gestion graphique   Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra          Installed
    [ ] Expérience utilisateur                          Desktop-Experience             Available
    [X] Shell graphique du serveur                      Server-Gui-Shell               Installed
[ ] Kit d'administration du Gestionnaire des connexi... CMAK                           Available
[ ] Media Foundation                                    Server-Media-Foundation        Available
[ ] Message Queuing                                     MSMQ                           Available
    [ ] Services Message Queuing                        MSMQ-Services                  Available
        [ ] Serveur Message Queuing                     MSMQ-Server                    Available
        [ ] Déclencheurs Message Queuing                MSMQ-Triggers                  Available
        [ ] Intégration du service d'annuaire           MSMQ-Directory                 Available
        [ ] Prise en charge de la multidiffusion        MSMQ-Multicasting              Available
        [ ] Prise en charge HTTP                        MSMQ-HTTP-Support              Available
        [ ] Service de routage                          MSMQ-Routing                   Available
    [ ] Proxy DCOM Message Queuing                      MSMQ-DCOM                      Available
[ ] Moniteur de port LPR                                LPR-Port-Monitor               Available
[ ] MPIO (Multipath I/O)                                Multipath-IO                   Available
[X] Outils d'administration de serveur distant          RSAT                           Installed
    [ ] Outils d'administration de fonctionnalités      RSAT-Feature-Tools             Available
        [ ] Outils du serveur SMTP                      RSAT-SMTP                      Available
        [ ] Client Gestion des adresses IP (IPAM)       IPAM-Client-Feature            Available
        [ ] Outils d'équilibrage de la charge réseau    RSAT-NLB                       Available
        [ ] Outils d'extensions du serveur BITS         RSAT-Bits-Server               Available
        [ ] Outils de clustering avec basculement       RSAT-Clustering                Available
            [ ] Module Cluster de basculement pour W... RSAT-Clustering-Powe...        Available
            [ ] Outils de gestion du cluster de basc... RSAT-Clustering-Mgmt           Available
            [ ] Interface de commande de cluster de ... RSAT-Clustering-CmdI...        Available
            [ ] Serveur Automation de cluster de bas... RSAT-Clustering-Auto...        Available
        [ ] Outils du serveur WINS                      RSAT-WINS                      Available
        [ ] Outils SNMP                                 RSAT-SNMP                      Available
        [ ] Utilitaires d'administration de Chiffrem... RSAT-Feature-Tools-B...        Available
            [ ] Outils de chiffrement de lecteur Bit... RSAT-Feature-Tools-B...        Available
            [ ] Visionneuse des mots de passe de réc... RSAT-Feature-Tools-B...        Available
    [X] Outils d'administration de rôles                RSAT-Role-Tools                Installed
        [X] Outils AD DS et AD LDS                      RSAT-AD-Tools                  Installed
            [ ] Composants logiciels enfichables et ... RSAT-ADLDS                     Available
            [X] Module Active Directory pour Windows... RSAT-AD-PowerShell             Installed
            [X] Outils AD DS                            RSAT-ADDS                      Installed
                [X] Centre d'administration Active D... RSAT-AD-AdminCenter            Installed
                [X] Composants logiciels enfichables... RSAT-ADDS-Tools                Installed
                [ ] Outils de Serveur pour le servic... RSAT-NIS                       Available
        [ ] Outils d'administration Hyper-V             RSAT-Hyper-V-Tools             Available
            [ ] Module Hyper-V pour Windows PowerShell  Hyper-V-PowerShell             Available
            [ ] Outils d'administration d'interface ... Hyper-V-Tools                  Available
        [ ] Outils des services Bureau à distance       RSAT-RDS-Tools                 Available
            [ ] Outils de diagnostic des licences de... RSAT-RDS-Licensing-D...        Available
            [ ] Outils de la passerelle des services... RSAT-RDS-Gateway               Available
            [ ] Outils du gestionnaire de licences d... RDS-Licensing-UI               Available
        [X] Outils des services WSUS (Windows Server... UpdateServices-RSAT            Installed
            [X] API et applets de commande PowerShell   UpdateServices-API             Installed
            [X] Console de gestion de l'interface ut... UpdateServices-UI              Installed
        [ ] Outils d'activation en volume               RSAT-VA-Tools                  Available
        [X] Outils de gestion de l'accès à distance     RSAT-RemoteAccess              Installed
            [ ] Interface GUI de l'accès à distance ... RSAT-RemoteAccess-Mgmt         Available
            [X] Module d'accès à distance pour Windo... RSAT-RemoteAccess-Po...        Installed
        [ ] Outils de la stratégie réseau et des ser... RSAT-NPAS                      Available
        [X] Outils de services de fichiers              RSAT-File-Services             Installed
            [ ] Outil Gestion du partage et du stockage RSAT-CoreFile-Mgmt             Available
            [X] Outils de gestion DFS                   RSAT-DFS-Mgmt-Con              Installed
            [ ] Outils du Gestionnaire de ressources... RSAT-FSRM-Mgmt                 Available
            [ ] Services des outils de gestion du sy... RSAT-NFS-Admin                 Available
        [ ] Outils des services AD RMS (Active Direc... RSAT-ADRMS                     Available
        [X] Outils des services d'impression et de n... RSAT-Print-Services            Installed
        [X] Outils des services de certificats Activ... RSAT-ADCS                      Installed
            [X] Outils de gestion de l'autorité de c... RSAT-ADCS-Mgmt                 Installed
            [ ] Outils des répondeurs en ligne          RSAT-Online-Responder          Available
        [ ] Outils des services de déploiement Windows  WDS-AdminPack                  Available
        [ ] Outils du serveur de télécopie              RSAT-Fax                       Available
        [X] Outils du serveur DHCP                      RSAT-DHCP                      Installed
        [ ] Outils du serveur DNS                       RSAT-DNS-Server                Available
[ ] Outils de migration de Windows Server               Migration                      Available
[X] Prise en charge WoW64                               WoW64-Support                  Installed
[ ] Protocole PNRP                                      PNRP                           Available
[ ] RPC sur proxy HTTP                                  RPC-over-HTTP-Proxy            Available
[X] Sauvegarde Windows Server                           Windows-Server-Backup          Installed
[ ] Serveur de gestion des adresses IP (IPAM)           IPAM                           Available
[ ] Serveur SMTP                                        SMTP-Server                    Available
[ ] Serveur Telnet                                      Telnet-Server                  Available
[ ] Serveur WINS                                        WINS                           Available
[X] Service d'activation des processus Windows          WAS                            Installed
    [X] Modèle de processus                             WAS-Process-Model              Installed
    [X] API de configuration                            WAS-Config-APIs                Installed
    [ ] Environnement .NET 3.5                          WAS-NET-Environment            Available
[X] Service de recherche Windows                        Search-Service                 Installed
[ ] Service de réseau local sans fil                    Wireless-Networking            Available
[ ] Service de transfert intelligent en arrière-plan... BITS                           Available
    [ ] Extension de serveur IIS                        BITS-IIS-Ext                   Available
    [ ] Compact Server                                  BITS-Compact-Server            Available
[ ] Service Serveur iSNS                                ISNS                           Available
[ ] Service SNMP                                        SNMP-Service                   Available
    [ ] Fournisseur WMI SNMP                            SNMP-WMI-Provider              Available
[ ] Services d'encre et de reconnaissance de l'écrit... InkAndHandwritingSer...        Available
[X] Services TCP/IP simples                             Simple-TCPIP                   Installed
[ ] SMB Bandwidth Limit                                 FS-SMBBW                       Available
[ ] Stockage étendu                                     EnhancedStorage                Available
[X] Support de partage de fichiers SMB 1.0/CIFS         FS-SMB1                        Installed
[ ] Transfert de commentaires sur Windows               WFF                            Available
[ ] Visionneuse XPS                                     XPS-Viewer                     Available
[ ] Windows Biometric Framework                         Biometric-Framework            Available
[ ] Windows Identity Foundation 3.5                     Windows-Identity-Fou...        Available
[X] Windows PowerShell                                  PowerShellRoot                 Installed
    [X] Windows PowerShell 4.0                          PowerShell                     Installed
    [ ] Accès Web Windows PowerShell                    WindowsPowerShellWeb...        Available
    [X] Moteur Windows PowerShell 2.0                   PowerShell-V2                  Installed
    [ ] Service de configuration d'état souhaité Win... DSC-Service                    Available
    [X] Windows PowerShell ISE                          PowerShell-ISE                 Installed
```

My issue is I can't install any new role with the GUI, can't start any service which need HTTP service.
Trying to manually start the HTTP service :

```
>net start http
L'erreur système 1058 s'est produite.

Le service ne peut pas être démarré parce qu'il est désactivé ou qu'aucun périphérique activé ne lui est associé.
```

It's in french, meaning the service can't start because it's desactivated or no device is associated to it.

I tried to install/reinstall IIS, I ran Windows Update, and tried to stop services installed by nxFilter and TeamViewer. No results...

Comment: maybe try installing the web server?  Specifically the `Web-Server` windows feature

Comment: I already tried, as the GUI won't work I installed it using powershell. Reboot, nothing same issue...

Comment: You couldn't have installed it..... when you ran `get-windowsfeature` the web server isn't installed.

Comment: I said "I tried to install/reinstall IIS". IIS = Web-Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it was completely broken from everywhere so I decided to reinstall completely during a night. 
Now everything goes well. That was a serious bug from 2012...